# When system font size is increased, how to change font size to 100% of particular Eclipse-RCP application

Tags: windows, eclipse-rcp, ini

I have created Eclipse-RCP application and its few parts or dialogs are not responsive.
When I increase system font size > 100% in Windows OS, font size changes in the application also due to it UI get distorted.
eg:- Label text get cuts, scrollbar doesnt appear so buttons at bottom are not visible.

As a solution would like to set font size for particular application to 100% by setting any parameters in .ini file.

Below are tried settings(after -vmargs in .ini file):

-Dswt.autoScale=100

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

Comment: Are you using Layouts for your parts and dialogs or are you using setBounds? You need to use Layouts. Show us an [mcve] of something that is not working.

Comment: Yes I am using bounds, set width and set height to specific size instead of layouts.
I will make UI responsive by making use of layouts.

Comment: Yes, you must use Layouts to be responsive. See for example [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the styling in your Eclipse application, you only need a css file and you can define to what components will be affected. It is similar to Web development, you can define classes, identifiers, etc.

Please check this link, there are many examples to change the font size and styling your app.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html